# change postgres.conf on mounted volume has no effect on container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a postgres container running with volume to postgres data on container

```
volumes
  - ./pg-data:/var/lib/postgres
```

After change `postgres.conf` on pg_data local folder and restart container that change not take effect on it.

What is missing ?

Thanks,

Comment: after restart changes are lost? see: [How to stop/relaunch docker container without losing the changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067032/how-to-stop-relaunch-docker-container-without-losing-the-changes)

Comment: No, I needed to change a propertie on postgres.conf (max_connections) and in docker container appears the old value and not the new one present on local postgres.conf

Answer (score 0):

I have run through a similar issue before, there could be many reasons for that not working, I will mention some:

1. Make sure you really save the updates you made to the file, it could be as simple as that
2. Make sure the files you are editing is inside the correct location (`./pg-data` in your case)
3. This step I'm not quite sure if it would help, but try to completely delete the container and then recreate it, sometimes restart doesn't let the container use the latest files version

I hope this helps and solves your problem, let me know how it goes!.